# Run time error 13 - While changing the pivotcache

Tags: excel, syntax-error, datasource, pivot-table, vba

Im new on this forum. I wanted to ask if anyone can help me with this. I wrote a macro that changes all the pivottables sources on which if the name of the pt ends with 1 it applies one source from another xlsx file and if its 2 it gives another one from another file. I keep both books open during the macro to make sure it doesnt break on that side. But in "case 2" it always throws the run time error 13 : type missmatch . Can anyone help me fix this. Thanks before hand!

```
Sub origen_tablas_fwb()

Dim hoja As Worksheet
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim a1, a2, j As Long
Dim libro1, libro2 As String

a2 = Workbooks("Global ETdlc.xlsx").Worksheets("Comando").Range("A7").Value
a1 = a2 - 1
Windows("Global ETdlc.xlsx").Activate
Sheets("Comando").Activate
j = Sheets("Comando").Range("N1", Range("N1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
libro2 = Workbooks("Global ETdlc.xlsx").Worksheets("Comando").Range("B8").Value
For i = 1 To j
    If Cells(i, 14).Value = libro2 Then
    libro1 = Cells(i, 15).Value
    End If
Next i

'Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Respaldo Reservas\FEEDS+FWB\" & a1 & "\" & libro1
'Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Respaldo Reservas\FEEDS+FWB\" & a2 & "\" & libro2

'Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Informes\Forward Bookings"
Windows("Forward Bookings").Activate
For Each hoja In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    For Each pt In Worksheets(hoja.Name).PivotTables
        Select Case Right(pt.Name, 1)
        Case 1
        'cambiar cache año anterior
        ActiveSheet.pt.ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook. _
        PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
        SourceData:=Workbooks(libro1).Sheets("Input").Range("A1").CurrentRegion)
        Case 2
        'cambiar cache año actual
        ActiveSheet.pt.ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook. _
        PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
        SourceData:=Workbooks(libro2).Sheets("Input").Range("A1").CurrentRegion)
        End Select
    Next pt
Next hoja
Windows(libro1).Close
Windows(libro2).Close
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is actually trying to create one `PivotCache` for each `PivotTable`.

I suggest to create just one `PivotCache` per external workbook then change the `PivotCache` of each `PivotTable` as it corresponds.

Replace your the part that changes the Pivot Cache with this code:

```
Dim Pch1 As PivotCache, Pch2 As PivotCache

With Windows("Forward Bookings")
    With .PivotCaches
        Set Pch1 = .Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
            SourceData:=Workbooks(libro1).Sheets("Input").Range("A1").CurrentRegion)
        Set Pch1 = .Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
            SourceData:=Workbooks(libro2).Sheets("Input").Range("A1").CurrentRegion)
    End With
    For Each hoja In .Worksheets
        For Each pt In hoja.PivotTables
            Select Case Right(pt.Name, 1)
            Case 1
                'cambiar cache año anterior
                pt.ChangePivotCache (Pch1)
            Case 2
                'cambiar cache año actual
                pt.ChangePivotCache (Pch2)
            End Select

Next: Next: End With
```